# Using a data-attribute with an array for checkbox inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox

I have multiple `checkbox`s that I am trying to write the data for in `#template-selection-review` if the `checkbox` is `selected`. When it is selected, I want the data from `data-template` to be used and put into an `array`, so that if more than one selection is chosen it will show up.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
$('.tp-template-check').on('change', function() {
  var templateSelection = {};
  
  $('.tp-template-check:checked').each(function() {
    templateSelection[$(this).data('template')] = $(this).val();
    $('#template-selection-review').html(templateSelection);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Winter">
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Spring">
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Summer">
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Fall">
<div id="template-selection-review"></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `object` as you snippet shown you've to set the `value` to the checkbox's, then convert the result object `templateSelection` to String before print it to the `#template-selection-review` :

```
$('#template-selection-review').html(JSON.stringify(templateSelection));
```

Else you could use array instead, then you don't need no value :

```
templateSelection.push($(this).data('template'));
```

Hope this helps.

**Snippet using object :**

```js
$('.tp-template-check').on('change', function() {
  var templateSelection = {};
  
  $('.tp-template-check:checked').each(function() {
    templateSelection[$(this).data('template')] = $(this).val();
  });

  $('#template-selection-review').html(JSON.stringify(templateSelection));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Winter" value='checkbox1'>
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Spring" value='checkbox2'>
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Summer" value='checkbox3'>
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Fall">

<div id="template-selection-review"></div>
```

**Snippet using array :**

```js
$('.tp-template-check').on('change', function() {
  var templateSelection = [];
  
  $('.tp-template-check:checked').each(function() {
    templateSelection.push($(this).data('template'));
  });

  $('#template-selection-review').html(templateSelection.join('<br>'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Winter" value='checkbox1'>
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Spring" value='checkbox2'>
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Summer" value='checkbox3'>
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Fall">

<div id="template-selection-review"></div>
```

Comment: How would I get it to just say Winter, Fall, or whatever the selection is?

Comment: Then you could use array, check my update.

Comment: This works perfect in your snippet, but for some reason it isn't working on my actual page.

Comment: Ok check your browser console, if is there any errors/warnings.

Comment: No error messages. Nothing is showing up. This is my real code (trimmed down). Do you see anything I could be doing to prevent it? https://jsfiddle.net/9qh711za/

Comment: The js code from this example in near the bottom oft he js panel.

Comment: Yes, the fiddle throw `Uncaught ReferenceError: limitTemplate is not defined` error

Comment: I think i found the problem `data-tempate` should be `data-template` .. https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/9qh711za/2/

Comment: Yep! That was it...thanks! Just out of curiosity. With this same set of code, if I was to add `data-template-img="<img src......"` Then write ouit the `data-template-img` would it display the img or will images not transfer with a data attribute?

Comment: That will works but it's not a good practice to store the HTML tags as attributes value else you can store just the `src` for example the when you get the `src` generate the `img` tag dynamically..

Comment: Thanks. I got that to work. I appreciate it.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the , that the join() produced?

Comment: The join will join using the delimiter passed example to joing with new line you could use `.join('<br>')`, so instead of comma `,` you could pass what you want...

Comment: I just want it to produce the items I am passing through and not break or put a comma. I added an image of what I have to my question. I am pushing the img in a `display:inline-block` fashion.

Comment: Ok please show me a fiddle that reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 1):

First, get checked boxes. Next `map` each entry to only return the dataset value. Finally, `join` the results:

```js
$('.tp-template-check').on('change', function() {
  $('#template-selection-review').html(
    Array.from($('.tp-template-check:checked'))
    .map(a => a.dataset['template'])
    .join(', ')
  )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Winter">
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Spring">
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Summer">
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Fall">
<div id="template-selection-review"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.tp-template-check').on('change', function() {
  var templateSelection = []; // the selected items array

  $('.tp-template-check:checked').each(function() {
    templateSelection.push($(this).data('template')); // accumulate the selected items
  });
  
  $('#template-selection-review').html("Selected Items:<br>" + templateSelection.join('<br>')); // show result after the accumulation is done
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Winter">
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Spring">
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Summer">
<input type="checkbox" class="tp-template-check" data-template="Fall">
<div id="template-selection-review"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

can you please try the below solution

The way I understood the problem is, are you trying to show "winter,fall". If Iam wrong please provide me the sample output you need, so that  can try again.

```
$('.tp-template-check').on('change', function() {
    var templateSelection = [];
    $('.tp-template-check:checked').each(function() {
        templateSelection.push($(this).data('template'));
    });

    $('#template-selection-review').html(templateSelection.join());
})
```